# Global Code on Window Initialisation

Tags: c#, wpf

Any way to create a global piece of code to run on the initialisation of all Windows like there you can create global properties for XAML through App.xaml?

I'm just curious as the piece of code I'm using relates specifically to interface but can't be set in xaml so must be in code so I have to write it into the constructor of each Window. Just wondering if there might be a work around.

Comment: are properties same for all Windows?

Comment: So far, yes they are.

Comment: just use you custom class inherited from window? and always when create new window use it instead window.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem with the concept of inheritance create Base class that inherits Window do your common stuff in that class . All of Windows that want this common functionality will inherit the base class.

> > Base class

```
public class MyBaseWindow : Window 
{
    //do your common stuff in this base class for all windows
    protected object MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

> > .cs

```
public partial class MyWindow : MyBaseWindow
{
```

> > xaml

```
<local:MyBaseWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MyWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
```

I hope this will give you an idea.